# Is there a way to remove all the adverbs and pronouns from the string in R?

Tags: r, nlp, statistics, topic-modeling

I'm new to R. While trying to perform topic modeling, I need to delete all irrelevant words from the dataset. Is there a function that can find the words that belong to a particular part of speech?

Comment: Package udpipe for pos tagging, read the vignettes. Or quanteda for textmining. Etc... Check the [cran NLP task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html)

Comment: thanks so much! udpipe seems to be a really good choice!

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
gsub(pattern, replacement, x)
```

where x is your character variable, "pattern" is the word you want to replace and "replacement" will be "". However, R does not know what a pronoun is. So you'll have to tell it by writing a list of all possible pronouns in the language your character string is written in. Then you'll have to repeat the deleating for all pronouns (or what ever kind of words) like this:

```
x <- "This is a character string in which I tell you how he deleted pronouns."
unwant <- c(
"I", "he", "she", "it",...)
unwanted <- c(paste(" ", unwanted, " ", sep = ""), paste(" ", unwanted, ".", sep = ""), paste(" ", unwanted, "!", sep = ""), paste(" ", unwanted, "?", sep = ""), paste(" ", unwanted, ",", sep = "")
)

result <- x
for(i in 1:NROW(unwanted)){
result <- gsub(unwanted[i], " ", result)
}

print(result)
```

Obviously, "..." means you'll have to insert all the words yu don't want, but I guess the internet has lists of all pronouns somewhere.
Edit: You have to insert empty spaces in front of and after the words so R won't cut the letters out of other words where they occurr. I added this via the `paste` function, where your pronouns are modified in several ways, e.g. in case they occurr at the end of a sentence.

Comment: I've edited some minor things, you might have to try to understand it and change errors if they should occurr (all possible cases of how the words could occurr in a text will have to be considered)...

Comment: I've just found a function stop_words which contains the adverbs and pronouns, as well as some other words which may add noise to the data. So I think I'll use it!